# SQL Server "AFTER INSERT" trigger doesn't see the just-inserted row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

Consider this trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER myTrigger 
   ON someTable 
   AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
  DELETE FROM someTable
         WHERE ISNUMERIC(someField) = 1
END
```

I've got a table, someTable, and I'm trying to prevent people from inserting bad records. For the purpose of this question, a bad record has a field "someField" that is all numeric.

Of course, the right way to do this is NOT with a trigger, but I don't control the source code... just the SQL database. So I can't really prevent the insertion of the bad row, but I can delete it right away, which is good enough for my needs.

The trigger works, with one problem... when it fires, it never seems to delete the just-inserted bad record... it deletes any OLD bad records, but it doesn't delete the just-inserted bad record. So there's often one bad record floating around that isn't deleted until somebody else comes along and does another INSERT.

Is this a problem in my understanding of triggers? Are newly-inserted rows not yet committed while the trigger is running?

Comment: The transaction is not yet committed (that's why you can rollback, which is really probably your best answer), but you can update/delete the rows since the trigger is in the same transaction as the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Triggers cannot modify the changed data (`Inserted` or `Deleted`) otherwise you could get infinite recursion as the changes invoked the trigger again.  One option would be for the trigger to roll back the transaction.

**Edit:** The reason for this is that the standard for SQL is that inserted and deleted rows cannot be modified by the trigger.  The underlying reason for is that the modifications could cause infinite recursion.  In the general case, this evaluation could involve multiple triggers in a mutually recursive cascade.  Having a system intelligently decide whether to allow such updates is computationally intractable, essentially a variation on the [halting problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

The accepted solution to this is not to permit the trigger to alter the changing data, although it can roll back the transaction.

```
create table Foo (
       FooID int
      ,SomeField varchar (10)
)
go

create trigger FooInsert
    on Foo after insert as
    begin
        delete inserted
         where isnumeric (SomeField) = 1
    end
go


Msg 286, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FooInsert, Line 5
The logical tables INSERTED and DELETED cannot be updated.
```

Something like this will roll back the transaction.

```
create table Foo (
       FooID int
      ,SomeField varchar (10)
)
go

create trigger FooInsert
    on Foo for insert as
    if exists (
       select 1
         from inserted 
        where isnumeric (SomeField) = 1) begin
              rollback transaction
    end
go

insert Foo values (1, '1')

Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Comment: Um...so long as you're not doing an insert on or after insert you wouldn't trigger infinite recursion.  Here Joel's trying to delete on insert which wouldn't cause the trigger to refire.

Comment: My recollection of the theory is a bit hazy but IIRC actually trying to decide that in the general case is intractable.  You could wind up with mutually recursive triggers or other things that can't be statically evaluated.  The 'standard' approach is not to support updating the changing data.

Comment: MSSQL allows nested and recursive triggers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Recursive triggers as discussed in the MSDN article aren't quite the same thing. If you update 'inserted' or 'deleted' it is computationally intractable to decide what should be seen by other triggers. Imagine if two or three or 10 triggers made updates - what is the correct data? What if the updates (or even whwther an update is made) are contingent on the contents of the rows? Now the correct answer requires the decision mechanism to interpret the triggers. Open Wikipedia and read about the undecidability proof of the Halting Problem.

Comment: Triggers definitely modify incoming data, that's the point.  We trust the db server not to go in circles within a table.  The danger is in coding a loop between two tables, that's when you get infinite recursio, but even that is hard to do because the operations between two tables are never symmetrical.

Comment: [It's simple to set up a test case demonstrating this is not correct](https://gist.github.com/1748337)

Comment: @MartinSmith - the example does nothing with inserted or deleted.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells - It is the example from the OP though that woks fine. Of course it is not a good way of doing this but the question was why that code doesn't work.

Comment: Ah OK I didn't realise that your answer was just referring to the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables as opposed to the data that has been inserted or deleted. So I thought your answer was attempting to explain the behaviour in the OP rather than offering an alternative. Maybe formatting them as code would help.

Comment: @MartinSmith - the question is about 3 years old now - most of the discussion seems to have arisen from confusion on this.

Answer (score 40):

You can reverse the logic.  Instead of deleting an invalid row after it has been inserted, write an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to insert *only* if you verify the row is valid.

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger ON sometable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @isnum TINYINT;

  SELECT @isnum = ISNUMERIC(somefield) FROM inserted;

  IF (@isnum = 1)
    INSERT INTO sometable SELECT * FROM inserted;
  ELSE
    RAISERROR('somefield must be numeric', 16, 1)
      WITH SETERROR;
END
```

If your application doesn't want to handle errors (as Joel says is the case in his app), then don't `RAISERROR`.  Just make the trigger silently *not* do an insert that isn't valid.

I ran this on SQL Server Express 2005 and it works.  Note that `INSTEAD OF` triggers *do not* cause recursion if you insert into the same table for which the trigger is defined.

Comment: Thanks, but I found that CHECK constraint may be even better solution

Comment: Yes, CHECK constraint is also good.  I assume Joel simplified the nature of his condition, and some complex conditions may not be best implemented in a CHECK constraint.

Comment: Right. It's important to us that the insert NOT fail, because that would crash the process doing the insert.

Comment: It's a tricky problem, because you're setting up a condition where the app *thinks* it performed an insert, but it didn't happen.  Could lead to data integrity problems.

Comment: If you don't want the insert to fail, use Bill's code, but instead of doing an insert into sometable, insert into a DIFFERENT error logging table, like sometableRejects.  Let the insert continue, and the app won't know which table it actually inserted into.

Comment: Bill your solution is a bad practice ina trigger. It will only work if one record is inserted. All triggers must be designed to handle multiple record inserts.

Comment: @HLGEM: Yep, you're right.  I've since learned that MS SQL Server triggers fire once for all rows in a given operation.  I've done most of my work with InterBase/Firebird and MySQL, in which triggers fire once for each row modified.

Answer (score 28):

Here's my modified version of Bill's code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger ON sometable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
  INSERT INTO sometable SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE ISNUMERIC(somefield) = 1 FROM inserted;
  INSERT INTO sometableRejects SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE ISNUMERIC(somefield) = 0 FROM inserted;
END
```

This lets the insert always succeed, and any bogus records get thrown into your sometableRejects where you can handle them later.  It's important to make your rejects table use nvarchar fields for everything - not ints, tinyints, etc - because if they're getting rejected, it's because the data isn't what you expected it to be.

This also solves the multiple-record insert problem, which will cause Bill's trigger to fail.  If you insert ten records simultaneously (like if you do a select-insert-into) and just one of them is bogus, Bill's trigger would have flagged all of them as bad.  This handles any number of good and bad records.

I used this trick on a data warehousing project where the inserting application had no idea whether the business logic was any good, and we did the business logic in triggers instead.  Truly nasty for performance, but if you can't let the insert fail, it does work.

Answer (score 12):

I think you can use CHECK constraint - it is exactly what it was invented for.

```
ALTER TABLE someTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT someField_check CHECK (ISNUMERIC(someField) = 1) ;
```

My previous answer (also right by may be a bit overkill):

I think the right way is to use INSTEAD OF trigger to prevent the wrong data from being inserted (rather than deleting it post-factum)

Comment: See my separate answer.  +1 to Dmitry.

Comment: It turns out the reason we were using a trigger is that the running code didn't handle insert failures well. In most cases, you're right, we shouldn't use a trigger. But the original question still might be relevant to someone, so I'm accepting the answer that addresses it exactly.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: DELETE from a trigger works on both MSSql 7 and MSSql 2008.

I'm no relational guru, nor a SQL standards wonk. However - contrary to the accepted answer - MSSQL deals just fine with both r[ecursive and nested trigger evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx). I don't know about other RDBMSs.

The relevant options are ['recursive triggers' and 'nested triggers'](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/30031). Nested triggers are limited to 32 levels, and default to 1. Recursive triggers are off by default, and there's no talk of a limit - but frankly, I've never turned them on, so I don't know what happens with the inevitable stack overflow. I suspect MSSQL would just kill your spid (or there is a recursive limit).

Of course, that just shows that the accepted answer has the wrong *reason*, not that it's incorrect. However, prior to INSTEAD OF triggers, I recall writing ON INSERT triggers that would merrily UPDATE the just inserted rows. This all worked fine, and as expected.

A quick test of DELETEing the just inserted row also works:

```
 CREATE TABLE Test ( Id int IDENTITY(1,1), Column1 varchar(10) )
 GO

 CREATE TRIGGER trTest ON Test 
 FOR INSERT 
 AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE FROM Test WHERE Column1 = 'ABCDEF'
 GO

 INSERT INTO Test (Column1) VALUES ('ABCDEF')
 --SCOPE_IDENTITY() should be the same, but doesn't exist in SQL 7
 PRINT @@IDENTITY --Will print 1. Run it again, and it'll print 2, 3, etc.
 GO

 SELECT * FROM Test --No rows
 GO
```

You have something else going on here.

Answer (score 4):

From the [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254.aspx) documentation:

> **deleted** and **inserted** are logical (conceptual) tables. They are
>   structurally similar to the table on
>   which the trigger is defined, that is,
>   the table on which the user action is
>   attempted, and hold the old values or
>   new values of the rows that may be
>   changed by the user action. For
>   example, to retrieve all values in the
>   deleted table, use: `SELECT * FROM deleted`

So that at least gives you a way of seeing the new data.

I can't see anything in the docs which specifies that you won't see the inserted data when querying the normal table though...

Answer (score 3):

I found this reference:

```
create trigger myTrigger
on SomeTable
for insert 
as 
if (select count(*) 
    from SomeTable, inserted 
    where IsNumeric(SomeField) = 1) <> 0
/* Cancel the insert and print a message.*/
  begin
    rollback transaction 
    print "You can't do that!"  
  end  
/* Otherwise, allow it. */
else
  print "Added successfully."
```

I haven't tested it, but logically it looks like it should dp what you're after...rather than deleting the inserted data, prevent the insertion completely, thus not requiring you to have to undo the insert.  It should perform better and should therefore ultimately handle a higher load with more ease.

Edit: Of course, there *is* the potential that if the insert happened inside of an otherwise valid transaction that the wole transaction could be rolled back so you would need to take that scenario into account and determine if the insertion of an invalid data row would constitute a completely invalid transaction...

Comment: Couldn't this rule potentially rollback a valid transaction?  Imagine this scenario. 1) Update a row to have a bad numeric 2) then insert valid data.  Wouldn't the trigger prevent #2 from ever suceeding?

Comment: I guess theoretically you're right.  I'll add an addendum to qualify that.

Answer (score 0):

The techniques outlined above describe your options pretty well. But what are the users seeing? I can't imagine how a basic conflict like this between you and whoever is responsible for the software can't end up in confusion and antagonism with the users.

I'd do everything I could to find some other way out of the impasse - because other people could easily see any change you make as escalating the problem.

EDIT:

I'll score my first "undelete" and admit to posting the above when this question first appeared. I of course chickened out when I saw that it was from JOEL SPOLSKY. But it looks like it landed somewhere near. Don't need votes, but I'll put it on the record.

IME, triggers are so seldom the right answer for anything other than fine-grained integrity constraints outside the realm of business rules.

Comment: It's for a spam filter. The spamming process needs to see the record getting inserted successfully, otherwise the spammer will just modify their spam techniques until it does. We don't want the spammer to know there's a REGEXP that catches his spam or he'll work around it.

Comment: So - a legitimate case for an intentionally hostile user interface. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the INSERT is valid, but that a separate UPDATE is done afterwards that is invalid but wouldn't fire the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

MS-SQL has a setting to prevent recursive trigger firing. This is confirgured via the sp_configure stored proceedure, where you can turn recursive or nested triggers on or off.

In this case, it would be possible, if you turn off recursive triggers to link the record from the inserted table via the primary key, and make changes to the record.

In the specific case in the question, it is not really a problem, because the result is to delete the record, which won't refire this particular trigger, but in general that could be a valid approach. We implemented optimistic concurrency this way.

The code for your trigger that could be used in this way would be:

```
ALTER TRIGGER myTrigger
    ON someTable
    AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
DELETE FROM someTable
    INNER JOIN inserted on inserted.primarykey = someTable.primarykey
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(inserted.someField) = 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "trigger" is doing something that a "trigger" is not suppose to be doing. You can simple have your Sql Server Agent run

```
DELETE FROM someTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(someField) = 1
```

every 1 second or so. While you're at it, how about writing a nice little SP to stop the programming folk from inserting errors into your table. One good thing about SP's is that the parameters are type safe.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question looking for details on the sequence of events during an insert statement & trigger. I ended up coding some brief tests to confirm how SQL 2016 (EXPRESS) behaves - and thought it would be appropriate to share as it might help others searching for similar information.

Based on my test, it is possible to select data from the "inserted" table and use that to update the inserted data itself. And, of interest to me, the inserted data is not visible to other queries until the trigger completes at which point the final result is visible (at least best as I could test). I didn't test this for recursive triggers, etc. (I would expect the nested trigger would have full visibility of the inserted data in the table, but that's just a guess).

For example - assuming we have the table "table" with an integer field "field" and primary key field "pk" and the following code in our insert trigger:

```
select @value=field,@pk=pk from inserted
update table set field=@value+1 where pk=@pk
waitfor delay '00:00:15'
```

We insert a row with the value 1 for "field", then the row will end up with the value 2. Furthermore - if I open another window in SSMS and try:
   select * from table where pk = @pk

where @pk is the primary key I originally inserted, the query will be empty until the 15 seconds expire and will then show the updated value (field=2).

I was interested in what data is visible to other queries while the trigger is executing (apparently no new data). I tested with an added delete as well:

```
select @value=field,@pk=pk from inserted
update table set field=@value+1 where pk=@pk
delete from table where pk=@pk
waitfor delay '00:00:15'
```

Again, the insert took 15sec to execute. A query executing in a different session showed no new data - during or after execution of the insert + trigger (although I would expect any identity would increment even if no data appears to be inserted).