# Trigger to update foreign key field after insert on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two tables:

- Table1 (surveyid [PKID], surveyname)
- Table2 (visitid [PKID], surveyname, surveyid [FKID - refers to Table1]).

After inserting a new row into `Table2`, I would like to update `Table2.surveyid` with the `surveyid` from `Table1`, based on matching surveyname.

I thought it maybe wasn't possible (or good practice?) to create a trigger to update the same table. But I seem to have created a trigger that will do this. The problem is that after insert, the trigger updates the `surveyid` for every row, instead of just the newly inserted rows.

This trigger code works, but how do I ensure the trigger only updates the `surveyid` for newly inserted rows, and not all rows?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_table2_fk
ON Table2
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table2
    SET surveyid = (SELECT t1.surveyid
                    FROM Table1 t1
                    WHERE t1.surveyname = Table2.surveyname)
END;
```

Comment: It already does that - that's what `AFTER INSERT` means. You have an error in your code; it's written to update all rows in the table where the WHERE statement matches. Did you read the SQL Server documentation for `CREATE TRIGGER`?

Comment: Yes, I just don't know how to restrict the where clause to only inserted rows. I've tried adding the 'inserted' table into the query because I think that's where the new insert information is held in SQL Server? But I'm getting it wrong because it just breaks the trigger every time.

Comment: There's an example of using `inserted` in [this answer])https://stackoverflow.com/a/405295/62576) to a very similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you MattM and DaleK, you've helped me figure out the answer. I was adding the inserted table into the subquery where clause before, instead of the query where clause. This does the trick:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_table2_fk
on Table2
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Table2 SET
        surveyid = (
            SELECT t1.surveyid
            FROM Table1 t1
            WHERE t1.surveyname = Table2.surveyname
        )
    WHERE Table2.visitid IN (SELECT visitid FROM inserted)
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the `inserted` table is the answer.

I'd use it to capture the visitids of the inserted rows, then filter by them in a WHERE clause on the end of your UPDATE statement in your trigger.

E.g.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER tr_update_table2_fk
    ON Table2 
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #VisitIds ;
    CREATE TABLE #VisitIds ( [id] INT ) ;

    INSERT INTO #VisitIds ( [id] )
    SELECT      [visitid]
    FROM        inserted ;

    UPDATE      Table2
    SET         [surveyid] = 
                (
                    SELECT      t1.[surveyid]
                    FROM        Table1 AS t1
                    WHERE       t1.[surveyname] = Table2.[surveyname]
                )
    WHERE       [visitid] IN ( SELECT [id] FROM #VisitIds ) ;
END
GO
```

Comment: Why on earth would you copy the contents of `Inserted` into a temp table? Thats called a "go slow" switch... Inserted is **already** a temp table of sorts, use it as it is.

Comment: I did not know that. On a not unrelated note, looks like I just found a way to wring some performance out of the warehouse. ;-)